# Unity3D - GameObject.Find() vs Inspector Assignment performance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile clone of pacman for android. Everything is working fine, but I am trying to optimize my game as much as possible.

Currently in some scripts I am finding `GameObject`'s by doing `GameObject.Find()` in the `Start()` function of my scripts, like this:

```
void Start()
{
    ghosts      = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ghost");
    pacman      = GameObject.Find("Pacman");
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
}
```

My question is, would performance increase if I made some of these `GameObject`'s inspector assigned variables instead of doing `.Find()`?

Would that increase the performance speed or would it make no difference seen as though I do a `.Find()` in the `Start()` function?

Obviously performance would decrease if it was called in the `Update()` as the script would try and find a `GameObject` every frame, but a `Start()` function would only search for it once?

Comment: not sure how to answer this. No you should not notice any performance change and yes when you use Find() in Start or Awake it only executes once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance at startup for this kind of things is totally negligible, Inspector assignment requires deserialization, while `Find` requires message dispatch, both are slow operations, if you think that matters, profile that.

I would anyway use

`FindObjectOfType<GameManager>() as GameManager`

wich is at least more typesafe, I would not use editor inspection if possible, because manual wiring is source of many little errors. So I give a human-time performance reason:

Do not use editor inspection because if you miss to wire something you will have to debug a nullpointer  wich on the long run will eat hours of your time.

You have anyway to use Editor Insection in cases where you do not have just to find 1 component, no workaround for that (unless you use Svelto or Svelto-ECS wich are rather advanced topics.)

Comment: Thanks v helpful explanation, one thing maybe to note for new developers like me is `FindObjectOfType<>()` finds first component of this type, so if you're sure there's only one component like this, then fine eg I'm using it in scene which hinges on hitting a `PolygonCollider2D` component. But for animator component same scene, I have more than one, so maybe I'll use `GameObject.Find()` for that or even the Inspector. Otherwise guess would need to use `FindObjectsOfType<>()` and a for loop, iterating to check if the desired component is in there, quite a few more lines of code, so less neat.

Comment: Oops sorry to add 2nd comment, but this answer provides more detailed explanation that actually for mobile games, Inspector assignment is _much_ faster than `GameObject.Find()` but then again, it still may not matter if your game is small. Also same page mentions `GameObject.FindWithTag()` much faster than Find() but FindObjectOfType() is much _slower_, but then again, most of time it still doesn't matter anyway!... : [link] (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1170097/which-is-more-efficient-gameobjectfind-or-public-g.html)